# sorting floats numerically - not in ascii order - in python

Tags: python, sorting, floating-point

This might sound like a silly question, but I've tried to find an answer that works without much success. I've got a list of lists:

```
for v in sorted(list):
    print v


[885.1, 12824]
[885.1, 19843]
[885.11, 1319]
[885.12, 1155]
[885.13, 12844]
[885.14, 33602]
[885.15, 11324]
[885.16, 44040]
[885.2, 119283]
[885.3, 8424]
```

I've iterated through my list using the sorted function - however that brings up the items in ASCII order as above - can they be sorted as floats in a human readable order? ie:

```
[885.1, 19843]
[885.2, 119283]
[885.3, 8424]
[885.11, 1319]
[885.12, 1155]
[885.13, 12844]
[885.14, 33602]
[885.15, 11324]
[885.16, 44040]
```

Do I need to create an index of somekind? Convert my floats to ints? Any help much appreciated.

David.

Comment: The original sort is already ordered numerically - 885.16 is less than 885.2(0)

Comment: In your input list you have _two_ values in which 885.1 appears first.  I assume you want those to _both_ appear in your output, right?  And you want them to be considered when sorting, correct?

Answer (score 3):

convert the float to string first and split it by ".":

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x:map(int, str(float(x[0])).split(".")))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a "natsort" (natural sort). A quick google on it gives me this: http://www.skynet.ie/~caolan/Packages/python-natsort.html (haven't tried it though). Maybe it helps you.

<sup>Oh and that's not necessarily ASCII sort, it's just the number order, you know, like the real axis</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You need to give sorted a comparison function. Something like the following:

```
sorted(list, cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(x[0], y[0]))
```

Just write the function you need for what you want and plug it in.

You'll probably want something like a reverse radix sort.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hack, but:

```
a = [
    [885.1, 19843],
    [885.1, 12824],
    [885.11, 1319],
    [885.12, 1155],
    [885.13, 12844],
    [885.14, 33602],
    [885.15, 11324],
    [885.16, 44040],
    [885.2, 119283],
    [882.8, 8424],
    [882.75, 8424],
    [885.3, 8424]
]

for v in sorted(a, key=lambda t: str(t[0]).split(".")[0] + ("%05d" % int(str(t[0]).split(".")[1])) + "," + str(t[1])):
    print v
```

Result is

```
[882.8, 8424]
[882.75, 8424]
[885.1, 12824]
[885.1, 19843]
[885.2, 119283]
[885.3, 8424]
[885.11, 1319]
[885.12, 1155]
[885.13, 12844]
[885.14, 33602]
[885.15, 11324]
[885.16, 44040]
```

Disclaimer: this assumes at most 5 places after the decimal point.  Adjust accordingly.